# How to sign PDF file in case need to chose specific signature?

Tags: cosign-api

I am very new in programming.
I need to sign PDF document, the user have more than 1 certificate 
(I have UserName, password, ID of specific certificate , Serial of specific certificate )

I am trying to understand, the order of methods i need to use and which methods i need to use.

Is it need to be like this?

1.Initialize SAPI Library : SAPIInit

2.Acquire SAPI session handle: SAPIHandleAcquire(SESHandle)

3.Personalize SAPI Session : SAPILogon(SESHandle, username, domain, password)

4. SAPIConfigurationValueSet
5. SAPISignatureFieldCreateSign(SESHandle, fileType, filePath, SFS, flags, "")
6. SAPILogoff(SESHandle)
7. SAPIHandleRelease(SESHandle)

Answer (score 1):

The order and methods are fine. These are the parameters that you should pass to the `ConfigurationValueSet` function:

```
ConfigurationValueSet(SESHandle, SAPI_ENUM_CONF_ID.SAPI_ENUM_CONF_ID_CERT_SERIAL_ID, SAPI_ENUM_DATA_TYPE.SAPI_ENUM_DATA_TYPE_WSTR, "{CERT SERIAL ID}", 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, but i still have a problem.

Comment: I get an error: "Failed to get the default certificate. The user has no valid certificate in the store".    My ID has a format like this : "11111111-aa11-1aa1-11aa-11aaa1a1a11a" (1-number, a-letter).  My Serial has format like this : "11 11 11 1a 11 11 11 11 11 1a".  What i supposed to use, ID or Serial?

Comment: You should use the certificate serial number, and without the inner blank spaces.